# Effect of a cushion on the average force felt

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I had a question about how a sitting on a cushioned surface, like on a couch etc. affects the average force felt by a person vs. sitting on a hard surface. I understand that stopping an object using a cushioned surface vs. a harder surface reduces the average force acting on the object, but when someone is sitting down, they aren't moving so how is the average force acting on them reduced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a cushion, the force is spread over a larger area, so the average *pressure* is lower. The total *force* is the same, it's the same as their weight obviously.

Since the pressure is lower, none of your pressure receptors register a painful level.

Answer (score 0):

When stopping an object with a cushioned surface, we're talking time-averaged force so that the work of stopping is spread over a longer distance and therefore by a reduced force.

For sitting stationary on a surface, the relevant quantity should be average force per area aka pressure. A cushioned surface spreads the force around more evenly. The average force on any small area should then not be especially higher than any other small area.